# Using Differentiate under the integral sign to prove $I'(x) = (x+1)I(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The purpose is to prove $I'(x) = (x+1)I(x)$. And the solution is :

Here $f(x, t) = (1 +\lfloor t\rfloor−t)/t^{x+1}$ ($\lfloor t\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $≤ t$), and $I(x) = \int_{1}^\infty f(x,t)\ dt,x > 1$. Since for $b>x>a>1$,
$$|f(x,t)|+\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right|\le \frac{b+2}{t^{a+1}}=g(t), t > 1$$

and $g$ is integrable, we may differentiate under the integral sign, obtaining
$I'(x)=(x + 1)I(x + 1)$ for $a<x<b$.

My question is how the last step is derived, as $f_x(x,t) = -\ln(t)(1 +\lfloor t\rfloor−t)/t^{x+1}$, thus $I'(x) = \int_{1}^\infty -\ln(t)f(x,t)\ dt,x > 1$. How does this turn to $I'(x)=(x + 1)I(x + 1)$?